# Java printing issues

Tags: java, printing

I am having a lot of issues sending documents to print to my printer via java, i am getting no error messages or anything and i can see the print job in the queue but it does not print anything out, I have reinstalled the printers drivers etc but no luck, the only luck I have had so far is one code working perfectly and sending and successfully printing out the document.

below is the java code that works :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.text.*;
/**
* The PrintText application expands on the
* PrintExample application in that it images
* text on to the single page printed.
*/
public class PrintText implements Printable {
/**
* The text to be printed.
*/
private static final String mText = 
"Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this "
+ "continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated to the "
+ "proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in "
+ "a great civil war, testing whether that nation or any nation so "
+ "conceived and so dedicated can long endure. We are met on a great "
+ "battlefield of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of "
+ "that field as a final resting-place for those who here gave their "
+ "lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and "
+ "proper that we should do this. But in a larger sense, we cannot "
+ "dedicate, we cannot consecrate, we cannot hallow this ground." 
+ "The brave men, living and dead who struggled here have consecrated "
+ "it far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will "
+ "little note nor long remember what we say here, but it can never "
+ "forget what they did here. It is for us the living rather to be "
+ "dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here "
+ "have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here "
+ "dedicated to the great task remaining before us--that from these "
+ "honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which "
+ "they gave the last full measure of devotion--that we here highly "
+ "resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain, that this "
+ "nation under God shall have a new birth of freedom, and that "
+ "government of the people, by the people, for the people shall "
+ "not perish from the earth.";
/**
* Our text in a form for which we can obtain a
* AttributedCharacterIterator.
*/
private static final AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);
/**
* Print a single page containing some sample text.
*/
static public void main(String args[]) {
/* Get the representation of the current printer and 
* the current print job.
*/
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
/* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
* and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
* text.
*/
Book book = new Book();
book.append(new PrintText(), new PageFormat());
/* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
* Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
* print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
* and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
* pages to be printed.
*/
printerJob.setPageable(book);
/* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
* and need not be done if the application wants to perform
* 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
* is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
*/
boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
if (doPrint) {
try {
printerJob.print();
} catch (PrinterException exception) {
System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
}
}
}
/**
* Print a page of text.
*/
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {
/* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
*/
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
/* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
* of the imageable area.
*/
g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
/* Set the text color.
*/
g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
/* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
* lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
*/
Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
pen.y += layout.getAscent();
float dx = layout.isLeftToRight()? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
}
return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
}
```

BUT

this is no what i want to do, ideailly i need to be able to send a document like a txt file to print and not just some text i have added so the code below does NOT work
, no error messages, even says printing done..... in the terminal, can see this job once again in the queue but never prints out anything, what am i doing wrong ?

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;

import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;

import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;

public class PrintTextFile {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException, IOException {
    String defaultPrinter =
      PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
    System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter);

    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/Documents/testDocToPrintUsingJava.txt"));

    PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(new Copies(1));


    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(in, flavor, null);

    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
    job.print(doc, pras);
    pjw.waitForDone();
    in.close();

    // send FF to eject the page
    InputStream ff = new ByteArrayInputStream("\f".getBytes());
    Doc docff = new SimpleDoc(ff, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob jobff = service.createPrintJob();
    pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(jobff);
    jobff.print(docff, null);
    pjw.waitForDone();
  }
}

class PrintJobWatcher {
  boolean done = false;

  PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
    job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
      public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      void allDone() {
        synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
          done = true;
          System.out.println("Printing done ...");
          PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  public synchronized void waitForDone() {
    try {
      while (!done) {
        wait();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will print a text file. You can use this if needed.

```
public void printimg() throws FileNotFoundException, PrintException, InterruptedException {
    String filename = ("item.text"); // THIS IS THE TEXT FILE TO PRINT
    try{
    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8; //  FILE IS .txt TYPE
    PrintService printService[] =
            PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
    PrintService defaultService =
            PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200,
            printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);
    if (service != null) {
        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, das);
        job.print(doc, pras);

    }
    }
    catch(Exception a){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OPeration Failed");
    }
}
```

This function can be used to print your text file. The libraries you should import are 

    import javax.print.*;
    import javax.print.attribute.DocAttributeSet;
    import javax.print.attribute.HashDocAttributeSet;
    import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
    import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;

Comment: thank you i tried the code above, but still am getting errors :( and can not run it as it captures the exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997549/java-operation-failed#comment19322091_13997549