# java - OPeration failed

Tags: java

i have the code below, but when i run it i get a message box appear saying OPeration failed, why is this doing it and what solution is aviable for it to run, the code should simply allow a user to print from a txt file

code :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.DocAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.HashDocAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;

public class printimg
{
    public void printimg() throws FileNotFoundException, PrintException, InterruptedException {
    String filename = ("item.text"); // THIS IS THE TEXT FILE TO PRINT
    try{
    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8; //  FILE IS .txt TYPE
    PrintService printService[] =
            PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
    PrintService defaultService =
            PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200,
            printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);
    if (service != null) {
        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, das);
        job.print(doc, pras);

    }
    }
    catch(Exception a){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OPeration Failed");
    }
}
}
```

am getting this error now :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: services must be non-null and non-empty
    at javax.print.ServiceUI.printDialog(ServiceUI.java:167)
    at printimg.printimg(printimg.java:20)
    at __SHELL8.run(__SHELL8.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)
```

Comment: A stacktrace of the Exception would be helpful

Comment: You should log or print the exception (`a`) to figure out what is the problem

Comment: i am using bluej and can not see any stacktrace or anything yet, am trying to debug it

Comment: There is no stacktrace because you're catching/swallowing the Exception.  It has nothing to do with which IDE you're using... You could just add `a.printStackTrace();` to your catch block if you want to see the stacktrace.

Comment: ah thank you will do that now and post the results, sorry i am very new to this !

Comment: Please don't post code or stack traces as comments.  They're unreadable.

Comment: It sounds like your PrintService array is null or empty.  You should consult the documentation for [_PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices()_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html) to search for possible reasons why.

Comment: thank you, also  String filename = ("item.text");,  where does this file need to be as i think this may be the issue

Comment: Um... it's pretty hard to answer that given that we know nothing about your environment.  Is this a standalone application, a web page, an Applet? Also, the stacktrace you've shown suggests that this issue has nothing to do with the filename (since the line of code that throws the exception does not reference the file at all).

Comment: at the moment it is a standalone app that is just the code above, i am using bluej

Comment: do you have a printer and assigned default printer?

Comment: yes i do, i have java code that succesfully prints to the printer but this does not :(

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the message because something in the try block of your code is throwing an Exception. Set a breakpoint on the statement inside the catch block, start debugging, and look at exactly what Exception is being thrown.

That will tell you what code is breaking. From there, you should be able to figure out how to fix it.